# Getting timeout errors after setting up SSL in Nginx

Tags: nginx, ssl, django

My stack is Django-Rest-Framework with Vue.js on the front end. I have all this running on one instance on Google Cloud (at least, it was running until I tried to implement SSL) with nginx as the web server and Gunicorn running the Django backend.

Getting errors like this currently:

```
xhr.js:178 GET https://example.com:8000/api/.../.../ net::ERR_TIMED_OUT
```

Here's my nginx.conf (in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com.conf`):

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name *.example.com;
        return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
server {
        listen 443 default_server ssl;
        server_name example.com;

        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/private/ssl-bundle.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/example.com.key;

        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:20m;
        ssl_session_timeout 60m;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

        location / {
                alias /path/to/project/;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }
        location /dist/ {
                root /path/to/project;
        }
        location ^~ /(api|rest-auth|admin)/ {
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_pass https://0.0.0.0:8000;
        }
}
```

I'm using axios to make xhr requests, and here is the header config that is relevant to this issue:

```
axios.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken'
axios.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken'
axios.defaults.baseURL = 'https://example.com:8000'
```

A few Django settings that might be relevant:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS =['www.example.com','example.com','127.0.0.1']
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL=True
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
```

Another issue I'm having is that the domain forwarding from http -> https doesn't seem to be working (i.e. I have to type https://example.com to see the site).

Comment: Check your firewall.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Doesn't seem to be a firewall issue. The errors I'm getting are either "Mixed Content...request blocked" or timeout errors. I have port 443 enabled.

Comment: What does "I have port 443 enabled" mean? Did you check your firewall or not? What was the result?

Comment: Honestly not sure what you’re referring to. It’s a Google Cloud instance and I haven’t had any issues connecting to it before this.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls

Comment: @MichaelHampton Appreciate that you're trying to help, but can you tell me specifically what to look for? "Check your firewall" is really not helping me. There are like dozens of settings there. What exactly am I supposed to be "checking"?

Comment: If you already check the firewall but still error please provide nginx error logs. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone wondering, it wasn't a firewall problem. I did end up getting this to work with some tweaks to the nginx config and a few other things. Posting here in case anyone stumbles on this like I did.

**Django config**

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['.example.co']
```

**axios config**

```
axios.defaults.baseURL = 'https://example.co'
```

**nginx.conf**

```
upstream django-api {
        server 127.0.0.1:8000;
}

server {
        listen 80;
        server_name .example.com;
        return 301 https://example.co$request_uri;
}

server {
        gzip on;

        listen 443 default_server ssl;

        server_name example.co;

        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000"; include
        SubDomains" always;
        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/private/ssl-bundle.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/example.co.key;

        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:20m;
        ssl_session_timeout 60m;

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

        location / {
                alias /path/to/project/;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }

        location /dist/ {
                root /path/to/project/;
        }

        location /api/ {
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_pass http://django-api;
        }

        location /rest-auth/ {
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_pass http://django-api;
        }

}
```